# How to update a column in MariaDB where the column name is the result of a subselect?

Tags: mariadb

How can a table column be updated where the column name is selected by reference?

The end result is pseudo materialised view where the column is updated based on a table that stores the column name.

Logically

```
insert into bond_data_mv
set (select parent_field_name
    from paragraphs_item_field_data
    where id = 27053) = 33;
```

In 2 queries this would be

```
select id, parent_field_name,parent_type
from paragraphs_item_field_data
where id = 27053;
```

| id | parent_field_name | parent_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27053 | field_para_identifier | node |

```
update bond_data_mv
set field_para_identifier = 'node'
where id = 27053;
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this kind of update.

Comment: start by looking at [declare cursor](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/declare-cursor/) and [execute immediate](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/).